# What is the best solution in MVC for Code analysis ruleset CA1506 (I do not want to suppress)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, code-analysis

I am using MVC3. I am getting following error when I run code analysis.

> CA1506 : Microsoft.Maintainability : 'MyController' is coupled with 94
>   different types from 25 different namespaces. Rewrite or refactor this
>   class's methods to decrease its class coupling, or consider moving
>   some of the class's methods to some of the other types it is tightly
>   coupled with. A class coupling above 95 indicates poor
>   maintainability, a class coupling between 95 and 80 indicates moderate
>   maintainability, and a class coupling below 80 indicates good
>   maintainability.

This is a controller class.

May I know what is the best solution to decrease class coupling for a controller?

Comment: ignore it! how can it justify 80 being good, yet 95 (just 18% more) being bad? Solution?... less actions, less functionality, websites should contain no more than [...thinking of random number...] 23 active features at any given time (15 goooood, 23 baaaaad)

Comment: really though, if you want to get rid of the warning, do what it says; we can't tell you what to change because we would need to see your code (which sounds much too large to be posting around here). First options I would go for would be to decide if you can split your controller out into 2 (or more) controllers

Comment: @BobHorn . Thanks for your concern. But the thing is that, in many questions I didn't get any answers from the experts and many questions I didn't find satisfactory answer so I keep my existing way. May I know in above both cases How can I mark answers for those questions?

Comment: @musefan . This is happening because, we have implemented export functionality for Word, PDF and Excel. This is the cause of it. Is it good for creating different files for each export for each module? (As all the export functionality does not have same structure, formatting and logic.) I already created common class for headers and footers but as I mentioned above, due to this reason I didn't create separate files for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @musefan, by the sound of it you need to refactor. I've just had a look at a controller in a project I'm working with which I consider to be on the borderline of lacking cohesion and needing to be refactored, and it's coupled to about 40 types.

Take another look at the controller and the area of your system it services, and see if you can split it up into fewer, more cohesive classes.

**Edit**

With relation to your Controller providing export functionality for Word, PDFs and Excel, I assume this means you have logic in your Controller which knows the details of putting together a Word export, a PDF export and an Excel export, including certain aspects common between the three formats which you've abstracted out (headers and footers).

If I've understood this correctly, one refactoring you could consider would be to move all the logic relating to headers, footers, structure and formatting into a different class behind an interface, and have your Controller reference that interface instead of referencing the various classes which manage those aspects. That would move coupling to various classes from your controller into the new document-handling class behind its interface, and perhaps drop the number of coupled classes to a level below that which FxCop finds acceptable.

Comment: This is happening because, we have implemented export functionality for Word, PDF and Excel. This is the cause of it. Is it good for creating different files for each export for each module? (As all the export functionality does not have same structure, formatting and logic.) I already created common class for headers and footers but as I mentioned above, due to this reason I didn't create separate files for it. Is it good create a different files for each export for each module?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your controller is too heavy.  I don't know that it necessarily means that you need to split the functionality into multiple controllers.  Rather, I suspect it means that you have loaded up your controllers with a lot of logic.  There are a few reasons why people tend to avoid this, not the least of which is that it makes the controllers harder to test.  More importantly, it is often a sign that logic that would normally be in a re-usable business layer has bled into your controller layer.  Given that controllers are mvc-specific, you are therefore coupling your business layer to a layer that is not agnostic when it comes to the presentation layer.

My suggestion therefore is to look carefully at your controller and see if you can strategically refactor.  Move business logic to a new business logic layer (service layer) and I suspect that will naturally resolve this issue.

Comment: I didn't write any business logic at controller level. This is happening because, we have implemented export functionality for Word, PDF and Excel. This is the cause of it. Is it good for creating different files for each export for each module? (As all the export functionality does not have same structure, formatting and logic.) I already created common class for headers and footers but as I mentioned above, due to this reason I didn't create separate files for it.

Comment: nice answer, after reading the OP's additional comments today I was pretty much thinking of responding with something like this... now I don't need to :D

Comment: It sounds like another layer for handling the export logic is in order.  I don't think it belongs directly in the controllers.  As I mentioned and as Darin mentions, controllers should be thin and not do anything beyond what they are minimally responsible for in the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your controller on a diet as Jimmy Bogard illustrates in this video: http://www.viddler.com/v/b568679c

Having a coupling with 94 different types from 25 different namespaces seems absolutely nightmarish. I can't even imagine how your controller looks like.

Remember: Adding classes and separating responsibility into classes is cheap. Putting all your code inside a single class is a maintenance nightmare. It's might seem cheap at the beginning but believe me, it will quickly become like Hell.

Comment: I know. But I have to. I do not have any other option except put all the export logic in different classes and call that class as mentioned by Steve Wilkes. This is also a overhead for anybody. We have to write different classes (for header,footer and structure) for different type of exports (PDF, Excel, Word) for different controllers (i mean module). Is it a good way? I tried thought of Partial controller but still compile time it will be consider as a single class so no mean of doing it.